# Route all traffic through StrongSwan VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, ipsec, strongswan

I'm new to this - please excuse my ignorance.  I have looked through many other similar questions to no avail.

Trying to set up a StrongSwan VPN such that client C can connect to host H, be assigned a virtual IP address, and access H's network.  (Due to practical limitations while I set up and test, C and H are currently on the same network - in fact they are VMs on the same physical PC, with the network in Bridged mode, so they get their own IP addresses.)

Using StrongSwan 5.3.0, Ubuntu 14.04 (on both C and H).

I run `ipsec up home` on C and the connection appears to be established. H can ping the virtual IP address assigned to C (192.168.0.1) and C can see the pings going to its virtual IP address (confirmed using tcpdump).

However, as far as I can make out, all traffic on C still goes straight out through C's network connection, not through the tunnel -- if I run `tcpdump ip proto \\icmp` on a third, test, server (T), and ping it from C, I see the requests with C's real IP address.  The same is true if I do a `wget` from C to T.

My config follows:

**# /etc/ipsec.conf on the host (H)**

```
config setup

conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    keyexchange=ikev2

conn rw
    left=192.168.196.50
    leftcert=moonCert.pem
    leftid=@moon.strongswan.org
    leftfirewall=yes
    right=%any
    rightsourceip=192.168.0.0/16
    auto=add
```

-

**# /etc/ipsec.conf - on the client (C)**

```
 config setup

 conn %default
     ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
     rekeymargin=3m
     keyingtries=1
     keyexchange=ikev2

 conn home
     left=192.168.198.74
     leftsourceip=%config
     leftcert=carolCert.pem
     leftid=carol@strongswan.org
     leftfirewall=yes
     right=192.168.196.50
     rightid=@moon.strongswan.org
     auto=add
```

H's real IP address is 192.168.196.50.
C's real IP address is 192.168.198.74.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to run

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

on the host to cause it to route the traffic out.

My client C can now see other machines on the local network, and SOME (but not all, which I don't understand) on the internet.

Comment: Where is the 10.0.3.0/24 coming from?

Comment: It was a long time ago I did this and I can't really remember, but I think `10.0.3.0/24` is the range of IP addresses which host `H` will assign to clients connecting.

Comment: I found explanation of these rules on strongswan wiki: **By way of example, let's assume the gateway assigns virtual IPs from the 10.0.3.0/24 subnet to its roadwarrior clients. The
following iptables rules will NAT traffic from that subnet to the gateway's eth0 interface (this works even for gateways that
have only one network interface).**  [wiki.strongswan.org](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling)